# How to disable CTRL press in power bi iframe

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are trying to build a writeback functionality in PowerBI. As a part of it as the user selects/clicks on a visual, we keep tracking it. Let's say the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and selects several data points on 2 visuals, the data selected of PowerBI js returns the last visual on which the user has clicked.

While trying to capture the keypress we are facing a CORS issue. Is there a way by which we can capture all the selected filters?

Answer (score 0):

Currently capturing selected data points from multiple visuals is not supported. You can select several data points in each visual using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

For example, lets say you have two visuals: visual 1 and visual 2.

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select a data point in visual 1 -> one data point in visual 1 is selected.
2. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select a data point in visual 2 -> one data point in visual 2  is selected.
3. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select a data point in visual 1 -> two data points in visual 1  are selected.
4. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and select two data points in visual 2 -> three data points in visual 2 are selected.